# How to cast object[] to double[][] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, casting

I have something like

```
var a = new object[2]
{
     new double[1] { 0.5 },
     new double[1] { 0.5 }
}
```

And I want to cast this to `double[][]`.
I tried `(double[][])a` and `a.Cast<double[][]>()` but it didnt work

Comment: It *isn't* either of things though. For example, you could write `a[0] = "Hello";` and that would be entirely valid.

Comment: When you know for sure its a double[][] so you can cast it why isn't it of that type in the first place?

Comment: @Ralf because I get the result from an external API, that could only pass me objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt of doing `a.Cast<double[][]>()` is *almost* correct. You can use:

```
double[][] b = a.Cast<double[]>().ToArray();
```

Explanation:

- The problem is that the elements of your list are `double[]`s, but they are statically typed as `object`. To change the static type of a list's elements, you use LINQ's `Cast<T>`.
- `Cast<T>` takes the type of the *element* as `T`, not the type of the resulting list (this is why your attempt to use `Cast<double[][]>`failed). `Cast<double[]>` yields an `IEnumerable<double[]>`.
- To convert this `IEnumerable<double[]>` to an array of `double[]` (i.e., a `double[][]`), we can use LINQ's `ToArray()`.

Note that this will

- create a new *outer* array (i.e., `object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)` is false), but
- the new outer array will reference the *same* inner arrays (i.e., `object.ReferenceEquals(a[0], b[0])` is true).

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ `double[][] b = a.Select(x => (double[])x).ToArray();`

another way is to use `Array.ConvertAll` method, It takes a callback function which is called for each element in the given array.

```
double[][] b = Array.ConvertAll(a, x => (double[])x);
```